# Restricting the format of an input tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Within an `<input type="text" />` tag how do you I mask the input field so that the user is resricted to the following format `[].[]` and in between the brackets can be any number of characters.

As an example:

```
"[Analysis].[Analysis]"
```

or a another example:

```
[Analysis-Result].[Analysis Result]"
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: It's not jQuery, but you might be interested in [the pattern attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_pattern.asp)

Comment: The pattern attribute mentioned by @moose looks good - but don't forget your server side checks as well! The user can modify the pattern client-side if they want to.

Comment: The pattern attribute looks nice though it isn't supported my Internet Explorer... Which usually is a huge problem... Basically it is just pattern matching, so why not use that to check on submit whether the pattern is good using javascript and ofcourse do the same check on the server as mentioned before

Answer (score 1):

Use this plugin http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/#demo